# Background image in Div not appears correctly on left but not right side

Tags: css, html

I have an image that is used to create a psuedo-shaded border around a main content area. However, it will only appear on the left side of the content, not the right. I know this is not a matter of image size, since we use a similar one for the footer (to create a boxed-in look). Below is the css for the section, can anyone tell me if they see something I need to alter, remove or add? I'm very new to doing web front-end/design so if you need anything else, please let me know. Thx

```
#main 
{
background-image: url('../../Content/Images/body_rpt.png');
clear: both;  /*add this so tabs go left! */
padding: 15px 15px 15px 30px; /*30px 30px 15px 30px; */
background-color: #fff;
/*border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;*/
-webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}
```

for comparison here is the footer section, which is working properly

```
footer, 
#footer 
{
background-image: url('../../Content/Images/body_bot.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #fff;
color: #999;
padding: 10px 0;
text-align: center;
line-height: normal;
margin: 0 0 30px 0;
font-size: .9em;
border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything that would cause your main bg image to appear on the right side... what I would do is create two seperate divs say if i have body > wrapper > col1, col2, I'd do body > wrapper > col1 (left border), col2, col3, col4 (right border) if I was to use an image for my border, I'd set col1 and col4 to 1-2% width.

Another approach is to use floats, and yet another is to use the build in CSS shadow property (I have no idea what your border looks like, use fiddelr???).

If I was feeling really new however, I'd take my bg image, open it in an image editor, take body length + border(left) + border(right) as my image width and set the border on both sides and use that as my background (static image approach).